# CTE not working for reversing a string

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using sql server 2008 R2 and at present i am learning SQL. Recently I tried using CTE to reverse a string but i am getting error as -

Type don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in col "Val" of recursive query "CTE"

I am using below mentioned code -

```
declare @string varchar(10) = 'mystring'   

with cte as (
select right(@string,1) as val, len(@string) as ln
union all
select val + substring(@string,ln-1,1),ln-1
where ln > 0
)
select * from cte
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong here why i am getting type do not match error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10) = 'mystring';

WITH    cte ( val, ln )
          AS ( SELECT   CAST(RIGHT(@string, 1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS val ,
                        LEN(@string) AS ln
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   val + SUBSTRING(@string, ln - 1, 1) ,
                        ln - 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    ln > 0
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
```

Or

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = N'mystring';

WITH    cte ( val, ln )
          AS ( SELECT   RIGHT(@string, 1) AS val ,
                        LEN(@string) AS ln
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   val + SUBSTRING(@string, ln - 1, 1) ,
                        ln - 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    ln > 0
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
```

Problem is `VARCHAR(10)` its type is not matched the type of expression `val + SUBSTRING(@string, ln - 1, 1)` which is `VARCHAR(1)`, `VARCHAR(2)`...

When using `VARCHAR(MAX)` the type of `val + SUBSTRING(@string, ln - 1, 1)` is also `VARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reverse string, then use:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(10) = 'mystring'    

SELECT REVERSE(@string)
```